# XmlDocument is called obsolete

Tags: c#, xmldocument, visual-c#-express-2010

Visual c# 2010 Express says that XmlDocument is obsolete, will this class be removed in the following versions of c# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using .Net Framework 4.0 in Visual Studion 2010 Ultimate and it is not marked as Obsolete here. Like Habib answer said its [`XmlDataDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatadocument.aspx) you might be looking at.

Moreover, marking a class as obsolete does not mean that it will immediately be removed from environment. Its just means that a replacement is there and we should use that replacement because obsolete class will be deleted from future releases. If you keep using it, you will have to change your code for future environments.

Answer (score 2):

[XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is not marked as obsolete infact it is [supported in .Net framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as well. May be you are getting the warning on [XmlDataDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatadocument.aspx), which is marked as obsolete.

Comment: XMLDataDocument is [documented in .Net framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldatadocument(v=vs.110).aspx) so its not going anywhere in near future, but you can't be 100% sure as .Net framework 4.5 is in beta version, its better if you move to newer constructs